# How to generate unique equal hash for equal dictionaries?

Tags: python

eg:

```
>>> a = {'req_params': {'app': '12345', 'format': 'json'}, 'url_params': {'namespace': 'foo', 'id': 'baar'}, 'url_id': 'rest'}
>>> b = {'req_params': { 'format': 'json','app': '12345' }, 'url_params': { 'id': 'baar' ,'namespace':'foo' }, 'url_id': 'REST'.lower() }
>>> a == b
 True
```

What is a good hash function to generate equal hashes for both dicts ?
The dictionaries will
have basic datatypes like int,list,dict,and strings,no other objects.

It would be great if the hash is space optimized, the target set is around 5 million objects, hence collision chances are pretty less.

I am not sure if json.dumps or other serializations pay respect to equality instead of structure of the members in the dictionary.
eg. Basic hashing using str of dict does not work :

```
>>> a = {'name':'Jon','class':'nine'}
>>> b = {'class':'NINE'.lower(),'name':'Jon'}
>>> str(a)
"{'name': 'Jon', 'class': 'nine'}"
>>> str(b)
"{'class': 'nine', 'name': 'Jon'}"
```

json.dumps does not work either :

```
>>> import json,hashlib
>>> a = {'name':'Jon','class':'nine'}
>>> b = {'class':'NINE'.lower(),'name':'Jon'}
>>> a == b
True
>>> ha = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(a)).hexdigest()
>>> hb = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(b)).hexdigest()
>>> ha
'545af862cc4d2dd1926fe0aa1e34ad5c3e8a319461941b33a47a4de9dbd7b5e3'
>>> hb 
'4c7d8dbbe1f180c7367426d631410a175d47fff329d2494d80a650dde7bed5cb'
```

Comment: Hash the stringified dict? No idea if this guarantees equality... e.g. if its keys (and its keys' values' keys etc) will be printed sorted

Comment: @Patashu , not that does not assure equal hashes, try doing it for equal dicts with different order of keys.

Comment: indeed, printing the dict appears to be printed sorted somehow (not sure how, though)

Comment: @njzk2 the ordering is not assured I guess,

Comment: funny, apparently it is platform dependant

Comment: on my python 2.7.3, with your example, a==b is True

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pprint module sorts the dict keys

```
from pprint import pformat
hash(pformat(a)) == hash(pformat(b))
```

If you want to persist the hashes, you should use a hash from hashlib. sha1 is plenty

Comment: That is a decent hack. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you sort before hashing? Sure, it may require non-negligible time to do it, but at least you can keep using a "good" hash function, i.e., one that shows good dispersion plus all the other desired properties. Moreover, if the idea is to save space it's probably because you expect lots of entries in the dictionary, therefore, the time saved by not sorting the set when using a "good" hash function will certainly be dominated by the lookup time when using a "bad" hash function as a result of a high number of collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
import json
import hashlib

a = # as above
b = # as above
c = {'req_params': {'app': '12345', 'format': 'json'},
  'url_params': {'id':'baar', 'namespace': 'foo' }, 'url_id': 'rest'}
d = {'url_params': {'id':'baar', 'namespace': 'foo' },
  'req_params': {'app': '12345', 'format': 'json'}, 'url_id': 'rest'}

ha = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(a)).hexdigest()
hb = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(b)).hexdigest()
hc = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(c)).hexdigest()
hd = hashlib.sha256(json.dumps(d)).hexdigest()

assert ha == hb
assert ha == hc
assert ha == hd
```

Comment: Please see my update in question. It may work at times, but not all the time.

Comment: Nice, but in case of different order of insertion it will give different results. He could use `repr()` instead of `json.dumps()` and sort the dictionary beforehand.

Comment: Correct, `json.dumps` doesn't guarantee the order.

Comment: `json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True)` guarantees order, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm with Tommi, doesn't json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True) fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a hash of sorted string:

```
>>> a = {'name':'Jon','class':'nine'}
>>> b = {'class':'NINE'.lower(),'name':'Jon'}
>>> def isdeq(d1,d2):
...    def dhash(d):
...       return hash(str({k:d[k] for k in sorted(d)}))
...    return dhash(d1)==dhash(d2)
... 
>>> isdeq(a,b)
True
>>> isdeq({'name':'Jon','class':'nine'},{'name':'jon','class':'nine'})
False
>>> isdeq({'name':'Jon','class':'nine'},{'class':'nine','name':'Jon'})
True
```