# Get intersection of list elements with different sublist datatypes

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, intersection, python-3.5

I have two lists, which contains list elements, e.g:

```
list1 = [['placeholder1', {'data': 'data1'}], ['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}], ['placeholder2', {'data': 'data1'}]]
list2 = [['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}], ['placeholder3', {'data': 'data5'}]]

intersection_result = [['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}]]
```

The structure of the sub-list elements is just an example. It can also happen that all the sub-list elements contains strings `['asdf', 'qwert']` or a mixture of string and numbers `['sdfs', 232]`. However, the sub-list structure is always the same (in both lists).

How can I get the intersection of lists elements which are identical in both lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you can get the intersection by checking and selecting [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) of the elements in the smallest list which are equal to ones in the larger one.

With a comprehension, this would look like this:

```
intersection_res = [l for l in min(list2, list1, key=len) if any(l == l2 for l2 in max(list1, list2, key=len))]
```

This uses, [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) with a key assigned to [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) to always select from the smaller list and check against the larger one.

This yields:

```
print(intersection_res)
[['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}]]
```

This comprehension can be trimmed down if you pre-assign the min-max lists or, of course, if you are always certain which list is larger than the other:

```
sm, la = list1, list2 if len(list1) < len(list2) else list2, list1
intersection_res = [l for l in sm if any(l == l2 for l2 in la)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, which would be **independent of the structure of your data**.
You can generate [signature hashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16735786/how-to-generate-unique-equal-hash-for-equal-dictionaries) (using json or pformat) for your data, and find common hashes in both list1 and list2.

**Demo** : http://ideone.com/5i9cs8

```
import json

list1 = [['placeholder1', {'data': 'data1'}], ['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}], ['placeholder2', {'data': 'data1'}]]
list2 = [['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}], ['placeholder3', {'data': 'data5'}]]
sig1 = { hash(json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True)):x for x in list1 }
sig2 = { hash(json.dumps(x, sort_keys=True)):x for x in list2 }
result = {x:sig1[x] for x in sig1 if x in sig2}
print(result)
#prints {-7754841686355067234: ['placeholder2', {'data': 'data2'}]}
```

- If your dictionaries have data which does not support json serialization e.g. datetime, pformat will work well, or you can use cPickle, `str` will also work for simple cases. You can make the choice based on your dataset and efficiency required.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham For most practical cases, yes. The `hash` part can be removed as well, and json.dumps with sort_keys will be unique string key too.